# Where can I see the actual values of BasedOnStyle?

Tags: clang-format

Where can I see the actual key-value pairs set in Google style? I can't find the definition in the clang repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be found in the Format.cpp file of the clang lib.
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/04ee232ff212b6c308e2ebc7b6125892681c54ae/clang/lib/Format/Format.cpp#L660

This is the start of the LLVM style, then the following functions after it hold the other pre-defined configuration settings. If you are looking at a different version of the code base, look for the function 'getPredefinedStyle' to find the sub-calls that are used based on the style chosen.